# Commands are available in the following places

Tags: command-line

I do not know why this happened but when I enter a command from terminal for example `gedit ~/.bashrc` I get the following error:

```
Command 'gedit' is available in the following places
 * /bin/gedit
 * /usr/bin/gedit
The command could not be located because '/bin:/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
gedit: command not found
```

This happens for also cat, shutdown command etc. How can I solve it?

Comment: It sounds like the `PATH` variable has been changed. What is the result of `echo $PATH`?

Comment: Did you edit `.bashrc` at some point changing the variable `PATH`?

Comment: The result of  ```echo $PATH``` is ```/storage/IntelFPGA/q18.1/quartus/bin```. Yes, I have edited ```.bashrc``` and add some  ```PATH```. Is this the cause of the problem? How can I add my path variables permanently instead of editing ```.bashrc```?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show the code from your `.bashrc` that modifies `PATH`. Apparently you replaced the value of `PATH` instead of appending/prepending to it. (Until this is fixed, you can run `/usr/bin/gedit ~/.bashrc`.)

Answer (score 1):

I have forgotten to add `:$PATH` at the end of the line in `~/.bashrc`. Adding it solved my problem. Before edit, it was like `export PATH="/storage/IntelFPGA/q18.1/quartus/bin"`.

Comment: Exactly, see also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path